# Converting System.Windows.Forms.Keys to the Win32 VK_* system

Tags: c#, win32gui

Is there a pre-existing converter from System.Windows.Forms.Keys to the Win32 VK_* system? I see that VK_CONTROL is 0x11 while System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control is 131072. (System.Windows.Forms.Keys.ControlKey is 17.)

Comment: FYI. 17 is 0x11 in Hexidecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WPF Key enumeration there is [KeyInterop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.aspx) class.

Winforms Keys enumeration has the same integer values as the Win32 VK_* values.